# Excel: logical operators in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

- I am trying to define a function that calculates the tax year a date is in.
- I want to do this using array-formula and have it be auto-generated

This is the full solution that I have:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
      ROW(A:A)=1,
      "Tax year",
      IF(
        ISBLANK(A:A),
        "",
        IF(
          OR(MONTH(A:A)>4, AND(MONTH(A:A)=4, DAY(A:A)>=6)),
          YEAR(A:A)&"-"& YEAR(A:A)+1,
          YEAR(A:A)-1 &"-"&YEAR(A:A)              
        )
      )
    )
)
```

But I have noticed it's not behaving the way I'd expect it to. So I tried to break it down to smaller steps. Here is a [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S0mJ3LimTBgcMimYxWM9PKKduhxLK8vSej1g8wy4TSg/edit?usp=sharing) where all the columns except for the ones with cyan headers are generated using array-formulae.

Note that:

- the demo has European formatting for dates.
- This is for calculating British tax dates, which starts on 6 April hence the logic around that particular date.

Observations:

- AND function is misbehaving as demonstrated by column F, ie header `M=4&D>=6`.
- OR function is misbehaving as demonstrated by column H, ie header `M>4 or M=4&D>=6`.

This behavior is observed on both google sheets and microsoft excel.
Is this a syntax issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={"Tax year"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
 IF((MONTH(A2:A)>4)+((MONTH(A2:A)=4)*(DAY(A2:A)>=6))),
 YEAR(A2:A)&"-"& YEAR(A2:A)+1,
 YEAR(A2:A)-1 &"-"&YEAR(A2:A)))}
```

Comment: ha just figured it out but you beat me to it! :) thanks!